# Alignment in algorithmic environment

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, algorithmic

I don't like how there is often a slight misalignment between assignment statements in an `algorithmic` environment. For example, the first version of the algorithm given below looks strange to me. I would like to be able to align the two statements, but the commented version in my example fails to even compile. I could always manually add some space to make things line up (see the last version below), but this is obviously not a good way to go about doing things for a number of reasons. Does anyone have a good way of making the assignment statements to line up?

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{algorithm}
    \usepackage{algorithmicx}
    \usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{Compute some stuff}
    \begin{algorithmic}
        \State \( x \gets 1 \)
        \State \( m \gets 2 \)
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

%\begin{algorithm}
%   \caption{Compute some stuff}
%   \begin{algorithmic}
%       \begin{align*}
%           x & \gets 1 \\
%           m & \gets 2
%       \end{align*}
%   \end{algorithmic}
%\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{Compute some stuff}
    \begin{algorithmic}
        \State \( \hspace{3pt} x \gets 1 \)
        \State \( m \gets 2 \)
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to use some "box manipulation":

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm,algorithmicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{algorithms,algorithmicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}% http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{Compute some stuff}
    \begin{algorithmic}
        \State \( x \gets 1 \)
        \State \( m \gets 2 \)
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{Compute some stuff}
    \begin{algorithmic}
        \State \( \phantom{m}\mathllap{x} \gets 1 \)
        \State \( m \gets 2 \)
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

I insert a box that has the width of the widest element (`m` in this case) using `\phantom`. This pushes the setting as deep is as necessary. Then I insert `x` using a `l`eft over`lap` (in `math`-mode; via `\mathllap` from [`mathtools`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools)). It takes up zero width, so it doesn't affect the spacing or "move the cursor" so to speak. The rest is set as usual.